# pandas dataframe check if index exists in a multi index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas Dataframe which has a multiindex created using the columns `userid` and `itemid`. df looks like this

```
                  0     1     2
userid  itemid
007     5000      9     4     3
007     4000      6     7     1
009     3000      1     2     3
```

I want to check if the index [007, 6000] exists in the dataframe df. How can I do that. If I run the following code there is an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

```
if [007, 6000] in df.index:
    print('it works')
```

Comment: The idiomatic in/not in of pandas is `isin`. Also, are those ints or strings?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this -

```
df

               0  1  2
userid itemid         
7      5000    9  4  3
       4000    6  7  1
9      3000    1  2  3

df.index.values
array([(7, 5000), (7, 4000), (9, 3000)], dtype=object)
```

You can use [`df.index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html).

```
df.index.isin([(7, 5000)])
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This gives you a mask corresponding to *where* that value can be found. If you just want to know whether it exists or not, use [`np.ndarray.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) in conjunction with `isin`.

```
df.index.isin([(7, 5000)]).any()
True

df.index.isin([(7, 6000)]).any()
False
```

Comment: I tried this approach and I get an error saying `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()`

Comment: @user77005 What, `len` is not part of my code anywhere. What are you running?

Comment: My mistake. I was not giving the indexes as a tuple. You suggestion works

Comment: Is there a way you can pass in a dictionary instead of a tuple?  It'd be nice if you didn't have to worry about the order of the levels of the index

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df.index.isin([('007','5000')])
print (df)
[ True False False]
```

Answer (score 0):

## cast `pd.MultiIndex` to `list` and check for presence in `list`

### code

```py
import pandas as pd

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(7, 5000), (7, 4000), (8, 3000)], names=['usedId', 'itemId'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[9, 4, 3], [6, 7, 1], [1, 2, 3]], index=mi)

print('df:', df, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
print('mi:', mi, sep='\n', end='\n\n')

print('Check for elements in Multi-Index:')
print('\t(7, 4000) in mi.to_list():', (7, 4000) in mi.to_list())
print('\t(7, 99) in mi.to_list():', (7, 99) in mi.to_list())
```

### output

```
df:
               0  1  2
usedId itemId         
7      5000    9  4  3
       4000    6  7  1
8      3000    1  2  3

mi:
MultiIndex([(7, 5000),
            (7, 4000),
            (8, 3000)],
           names=['usedId', 'itemId'])

Check for elements in Multi-Index:
    (7, 4000) in mi.to_list(): True
    (7, 99) in mi.to_list(): False
```